# Zeitz's ACoPS vs Larson's PSTP

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Which of the following books is better to prepare for a mathematical competition at the undergraduate level?

[The art and craft of problem solving (ACoPS)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471789011) or [Problem solving through problems (PSTP)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961712).

I think that ACoPS doesn't have an abstract algebra chapter and PSTP doesn't have a combinatorics chapter, so, which one would you recommend me to use and why (I can't use both right now)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with ACoPS because this book teaches you how to solve hard problems, and gives you ideas and techniques that are quite new that you can use them again or refine them so you can solve a broader class of questions.

Comment: Thank you!. Since you are a "heavy" user in MSE, I will listen to you!

Comment: Thanks....   See you around....